# SendMessageW WM_SetText usage for Multilanguage

Tags: c#, unicode, multilingual, sendmessage, settext

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, SendMessageFlags msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
public static void SetByHwnd(IntPtr hwnd, string text)
    {
        IntPtr a = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(text);
        SendMessage(hwnd, SendMessageFlags.WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, a);
    }
```

When i try to change any objects text to Japanese, Russian, Greek, Arabic etc.. text im changing my controls text to meaningless question marks.
There is no problem with the "a-Z" "0-9" but i need to use other languages alphabets too.
i need this to work **SetByHwnd(hwnd, "कार्यकारी")**
I tried to use SendMessageA and SendMessage, changed parameters like

---

```
SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, SendMessageFlags msg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder strBuffer);
SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, SendMessageFlags msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
```

But didnt help. Always seeing the question marks "????" in my control.

Comment: Crystal ball says that the window you are trying to poke was created with CreateWindowExA() instead of CreateWindowExW().  You can use SendMessageW() to send a Unicode string but the OS has to translate it to an ansi string to keep the window happy.  That inevitably produces question marks if the glyphs you use are not supported by the default system code page.  No workaround, you have to use CreateWindowExW() or use glyphs that the user knows how to read in his native language.  Fwiw, test localization only on an OS that matches the language you are trying to localize to.

Comment: I found SetThreadLocale and CreateRemoteThread in winapi. What if i combine this two function and call SetThreadLocale like im another thread. Can it work in runtime? Is there any chance or another functions to make this work?